# Function returning pointer to string

Tags: c, linux, function, pointers

I have a function returning `char**` i.e. pointer to array of characters. Here I am reading a file in number of directories for a specific integer value `ind`. If it finds the value in the file, it should return the name of the directory. I tried using static allocation but it wont help because returning those variables results in undefined behaviour. In my case I get the all the values same as the last directory name. This probably happens because I am reading from the allocated system stack. I then used dynamic allocation and Here is the code I have written:

```
//Global variable
int found = 0;

char** get_strings(int ind)
{
FILE *fp;
char filename[64];
char name[16];
//char *name;
char **array;
int i = 0, found = 0, l = 0;
int val = 0;

     char **array = (char **)malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
for(l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    array[l] = (char *)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));

     //name = (char *)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));

for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * 64, "/home/ben/dir%d/name", i);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp == NULL) 
    {
            perror("Error opening file");
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &val);
    fclose(fp);
    //printf("value-%d is %d\n", i, val);

    if (val != 0 && val == ind)
    {
        snprintf(name, sizeof(char) * 16, "dir%d", i);

        printf("Dir %s is a has %d\n", name, ind);
        strncpy(array[found],name, strlen(name));
        found++;
    }
}
return array;
}
```

and I am calling it in main function as:

```
int i = 0;
char **array;
array = get_strings(1);
for(i=0;i< found;i++)
    printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, array[i]);
```

I get garbage value in the output. Can somebody help?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is reduntant and will always evaluate to 1. Also, you don't need to typecast to convert to/from `void*` in C. It's implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you should not be using strncpy(). Use strcpy(). Try it... also, allocate + 1 in the malloc.

Reason: memory allocated by malloc is not pre-initialized to all zeros. So, your strings there are probably not terminated properly and it will overflow when you call printf. The extra +1 I recommend is simply to store the null byte that is needed in addition to the 16 actual chars you want to store.

Also, for(i=1;i<=10;i++) is wrong. loop from 0 to < 10, and then in your snprintf, use i + 1.

EDIT: by the way, there's a function strdup() which will allocate a string. To use it, i would recommend:

1/ allocate your array with:

```
char **array = calloc(10, sizeof(char *));
```

this will pre-initialize all the members to NULL so you won't need to pre-allocate the strings OR put NULL in the slots. Which makes it ready for:

2/ copy the strings in with strdup() if you want to store them:

```
if(conditions are ripe)
    array[found++] = strdup(name);
```

So now, your loops will go from 0 to < found. If you choose to de-allocate the array of arrays, only call free() on the slots from 0 to < found.

Comment: It makes no functional difference in this case whether or not they're using `strncpy` or `strcpy`. They're basically passing `strncopy` what `strcopy` would pass it.

Comment: I dont think there is a problem with the for loop. I am not using it for the array anyhow. Its just for modifying the directory name and file opening. I am using a global variable `found` for array indexing.

Comment: Hi I am not getting seg fault now somehow. I am now getting garbage value in the output. can you explain why?

Comment: your code is working and i changed my malloc to calloc and strncpy to strdup but No it still is not working. Still receiving the garbage values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GuruAdrian. I made some silly mistakes and now I can get the desired results using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory for 10 strings:

```
malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
```

...which means that valid array indices are 0 up to (including) 9. In particular, 10 is not a valid index. Try adjusting your loops to

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

Comment: That's not the only problem, but probably what's causing it.

Comment: I dont know what the for loop has to do with the array indices. I am not using the loop for accessing array elements.

Comment: @BenWilliams You wrote that you execute `for(i=1;i<=10;i++) printf("array[%d] = %s\n", i, array[i]);` in your main function, and `array` is the array returned by your function.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Sorry my bad. I corrected the loop in the code i posted.